# GitHub Pages custom domain setup issue, links to a site that asks for a few thousand dollars for my domain name

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm new to making websites. I wanted to make a plain text file and display it on GitHub pages, so I made one and gave it plain text. It's called Test.txt. I made a readme file because a website said I should, and that the website starts from that page. I gave it a HTML paragraph and that's all. Then I chose a domain name.

Then when I tried to access my site, which I'd hoped would show the text file from the directory, it linked to another site.

here is the website, called https://nittynitpicker.github.io/TestPage.

My GitHub repo [is here](https://github.com/nittynitpicker/TestPage/tree/main). It should be basic.

My HTML code is basic. This is what it looks like:

```
<p>this is a test</p>
```

It is a plain text paragraph done in HTML, which should show up when I click the shared link. Instead, a random company’s website appears, asking people for a few thousand dollars for a domain name.

I just want the plan text showing “this is a test” to display when clicking the link and that is all.

If someone has a good guide for people with 0 experience, I don’t mind a link at all. This should not be necessary however. I’d made a static site on neocities.org with ease and it should be just as easy on Github Pages, without reading any instructions. It should be this basic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the main file index.html, and do nothing to the domain name. Here is the [working site](https://nittynitpicker.github.io/) which follows [this tutorial](https://www.codecademy.com/article/creating-a-website-on-github-pages) from codecademy word-for-word. I may change my site at a later date.

Comment: I still haven’t done a custom domain name but I’ll do that next.